# Testing an injected config with spring without spring test runner

Tags: testing, spring-test

Given the following class:

> public class ClassToBeTest{
>
> > ${property.utility}
> >
> > private String property;
> >
> > private Utility utility;
> >
> > public ClassToBeTested(Utility utility){
> >
> > > this.utility = utility;
> >
> > }
> >
> > public void doSomething(){
> >
> > > utility.doSomething(property);
> >
> > }
>
> }

We want to Mock Utility (we are using Mockito for instance) and verify that utility.doSomething is called passing the property parameter.

We don't really care about the config value (we have other tests for that). But we don't want to open the class with a method like (or passing the property by constructor).

> public void setPropertyForTest(String property){
>
> > this.property = property;
>
> }

Is there other ways to check that this private property (with no value) is passed to Utility?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to set the `private` field, Spring (not *Sprint*) provides support for that in the `spring-test` module. See the `setField()` variants in [ReflectionTestUtils](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html).

Regards,

Sam

Comment: Agilism did so harm to me :)